# python - how can I set a multiline json in a variable?

Tags: python

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
def myjson = '
    {
        "json":true
    }
'
```

How can I do this in python?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
myjson = """
   {
       "json": true
   }
"""
```

Python triple quoted string literals preserve newlines, etc so you can put them directly into your code.  (triple single quotes would also work)...

Answer (score 0):

**def** is a reserved python keyword used for function declaration. On the other hand, python does not reserve any keyword for declaring variables